# side by side float center css

Tags: html, css, center

I am trying to center two images side by side, but for some reason it always displays the images on the left. Does anyone know how I could get them centered and next to each other?

Thanks!

```css
#container {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #665544;
  text-align: center;
}

#box1,
#box2 {
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  min-height: 200px;
  color: white;
}

#box1 {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #111;
}

#box2 {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="box1">
    <h1>header1</h1>
    <p>aaa</p>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <h1>header2</h1>
    <p>bbb</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @jack I guess OP's concern is to align them horizontal centered, in that case you might be right. It is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: left` and use `display: inline-block`

```
#box1, #box2 {
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 200px;
    color: white;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;

  border: 1px solid #665544;
  text-align: center;
}

#box1, #box2 {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 200px;
  
  color: white;
}

#box1 {
     width: 200px;
     background-color: #111;
}

#box2 {
     width: 200px;
     background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="box1">
 <h1>header1</h1>
 <p>aaa</p>
</div>

<div id="box2">
<h1>header2</h1>
<p>bbb</p>
</div>

</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rq5y72h/)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED -You can use a grid.

```
#container {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #665544;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .box {
        width: 250px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        display: block;
        min-height: 200px;
        color: white;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    #box1 {
        background-color: #111;
    }

    #box2 {
        background-color: #777;
    }
```

Comment: @jack Code Updated

Comment: OP needs to align both divs on the same line, side by side.

Answer (score -1):

Remove float: left; from #box1, #box2 and add display: inline-block;
ps: it's better if you use .box instead #box1, #box2

or use twitter Bootstrap (Grid system)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1px solid #665544;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .box {
            width: 250px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            display: inline-block;
            min-height: 200px;
            color: white;
        }

        #box1 {
            background-color: #111;
        }

        #box2 {
            background-color: #777;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">

    <div id="box1" class="box">
     <h1>header1</h1>
     <p>aaa</p>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box">
     <h1>header2</h1>
     <p>bbb</p>
    </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```